# Hibernate inconsistent in temporal return type (Date vs. Timestamp)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, date

I am writing test code with Hibernate atop an H2 in memory database. I have 2 projects with nearly identical configuration. In each, the test code builds the database schema automatically, from the model classes. Both classes define the data type the same way:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column("MY_DATE")
private java.util.Date myDate;
```

From the hibernate debug logs, I can see that the column created is of the same type for both projects:

```
create table MY_TABLE (
    ...
    MY_DATE timestamp,
    ...
)
```

The test models are always given an object of type `java.sql.Date`

For some reason though, in one project, when I retrieve the data with a Hibernate query, the type is `java.sql.Date`, and in the other project, it is `java.sql.Timestamp`.

What could possibly be causing this difference of behavior, and how do I get this data as a `java.sql.Date`, consistently?

(Keep in mind, I only have control of the test code. I can't change the application code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing a Hibernate query, if it shows a `java.sql.Date` instance, it is an instance being cached in the Hibernate session, not actually being reassembled from persisted data. When it returns the `java.sql.Timestamp` instance, this is actually being assembled from persisted data, based on the `Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`. To get, consistently, a `Timestamp`, make sure to use `Session.evict` before querying the data. Getting, consistently, a `Date` instance is not possible within the parameters of the question (i.e. it would require changing the application code).

(Thanks, and upvotes to Ben, for putting me on the right track.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure sure why they would be coming back differently - are you seeing this behaviour in ALL similar date fields between the two projects? That said - even though they are coming back differently, you mentioned you'd like to get them back consistently as `java.sql.Date` - which is not how they are mapped. The correct type based on the mapping that you *should* expect be getting back is `java.sql.Timestamp`. If you want `java.sql.Date` you should be using `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)`.

Either way - in your code you should only be coding against `java.util.Date` and not against the underlying `java.sql.*` classes.

Even more ideally, you'd use `java.time.LocalDateTime` (or the zoned equivalent thereof) if you're on Java 8, or else `org.joda.LocalDateTime` if not.

`java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` are nightmare hellrides :)

Comment: Upvoted for the recommendation of `LocalDateTime` or the zoned equivalent. If you are using Java 6 or 7, some say that today [the backport of `java.time`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) is a better choice than Joda-Time.

Comment: Upvoted because it put me on the right track. Even though, in application code, one would want to reference only the java.util.Date, this is not possible in test code. I need to make use of `.equals` to compare the dates returned from Hibernate, and `Timestamp.equals`  returns false for instances of `Date`, even when they have the same millisecond value. Unless there is something that I am missing here, that is.